# Asp.net after logged in load the same page with partial changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have my login form on my Layout(master page), after the user login, do I have to redirect the user to the new page ? or I can only make some partial changes on my Layout as html css changes,I want to replace the login form with user profile after the user logged in. I know some about partial views but couldn't be sure, Thanks for help.

"If anything is mess I am sorry."

HTML:

```
<div class="sign-in">
                    <form autocomplete="off">
                        <fieldset>
                            <input id="username" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
                            <hr>
                            <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password" required>
                            <button type="submit">Login</button>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
    <div id="container">
                <p>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Some Data 
                </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sign-in{
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  height:auto;
}
.sign-in button {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 3.6vw;
                    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
                    border: 0.3vw solid #dedede;
                    background-color: #262d37;
                    margin-top:2vw;

                }
#container{
  width:60%;
  height:100px;
  background-color:gray;
  float:right;
  padding:6px;
}
#holder{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fcx9g52d/)

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using .net MVC. Layout pages are there go put common design elements for all child pages. Since the login page has specific design elements (not common to be shown in other pages) it's html should not reside in a Layout page.

I would suggest not to use a master page for login (since it's design and content is unique). Just make a normal page for login. For your other pages depending on common content usage you can create a master page. From your login page later on you will redirect to another page.

Comment: Yes I do use .net MVC5.
Thanks for your suggestion but I am not able to make changes about my login page cause the design is almost done :/ As well let's assume I make some changes for login so I need the user profile on my Layout cause the profile page is fixed position and will be shown always whatever the content or page...

Comment: After login page you will already know the identity of the client (since you let him log in and send to next page), hence you can show all the information about the use on any page with various techniques. You can pull the information from database, you can store it in session state, you can store it in cookies etc.

Comment: I really would like to help more. Can you give more info? How do you log the user in? You probably ask for username/password. And then do you lookup a database, where is your user data?

Comment: I really appreciate your help, it is hard to upload my codes but I ll try to explain it more clearly. By the way I have my html and css only thus I am checking what to do best.

It is kind of E-commerce:
Full width navigator on top of page
Left side aside bar contain login box, below login box filters
Next to aside bar I have my content which changes depend on page
Footer usual usage on the bottom
So those are fixed position(except content) for all pages thus I use them as Layout
While the user logged in from login box, login box must change to user profile info + control panel for user's adv.

Comment: ok now I understand.  In your case you could use partials or you could put all html for login and post login in your layout with an if condition. If user is logged in show this html and not other. The same if coindition you will also use when you go partials way. The benefit of partial in this case would be simply the overall html content of your layout file.  @if (UserLoggedIn){@Html.Partial("Partial_UserProfile",null)} else{@Html.Partial("Partial_LoginForm",null)}

Comment: Thank you TSungur for your help I want to ask you one more question, should I keep my logged in partial html and css anywehere as a html page or I ll just write html and css code while I am declaring my function ?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question right. Your html for login box should go in one partial_login.cshtml file and html for user profile should go in partial_userprofile.cshtml file. I advice putting the styles in a separate .css file and link the css in the master layout page so all pages using this master can handle login-box and/or user-profile-box. The if statement I mentioned above will go to the layout page. So every page using this master can show user profile or login box depending on user state.